# How do you Download a minecraft map on the XBox360?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

A youtube user made a map, but I don't know how to download it.

I am trying to download a map to Minecraft on the Xbox 360 - can I do this? If yes, how?

Answer (score 4):

Note: This answer is for windows.

## Required

- Computer
- USB Drive
- Xbox 360 Console

## Steps

Plug in your USB Drive into the front of your Xbox.

Boot up your Xbox 360. Navigate to "system settings" (click the home button and go all the way to the right to find this). Navigate to Storage. Open "hard drive" storage, or "system" storage (wherever you store your profiles and games) and move your profile to the USB drive. Open your xbox storage, click "Games", and then "Minecraft". Click on a world you don't need and move it into your USB drive.

Now we will go into your computer. Disconnect your USB drive from the Xbox and plug it into your computer.

Download Horizon from [here](https://www.wemod.com/horizon) (this may be
falsely detected at a virus, but Horizon is safe to download).

Now download a Minecraft Xbox 360 map you would like to play (as a ".bin" file).

Now open horizon and you should see your USB drive on the right side in the file area. Now open Games, you should see Minecraft. Right click Minecraft and click inject file. Choose the map you downloaded. Click on the new map and transfer it to your profile. After the transfer is successful, close horizon and eject your USB drive.

Go back to the Xbox 360 and plug your USB drive in your Xbox.

Navigate to "system settings" (click the home button and go all the way to the right to find this).

Open storage and go in your USB drive. Move the Minecraft world you just downloaded to your Xbox storage. Move your profile back to your Xbox storage.

Once all that is done, go to Minecraft and you should be able to play the map!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot trivially download custom maps to the Xbox 360 version of Minecraft.

Answer (score 0):

Horizon will give you a virus, but there is another option, download Modio 5 and get a .bin or .so file of the map. When you have the map, go into Modio 5 and click "Open a Save", then choose the file and download it to your account, make sure to have your account and minecraft game on the usb, or it wont work. Please dont say clickbait, it works.